# Is a 92 Subaru Liberty Engine An Interferrance Motor?

Tags: subaru, timing-belt

I have a 1992 Subaru Liberty(/Legacy) that is due for a timing belt change. It is the single overhead cam 2.2l engine.

Is this engine interferrance ? If the timing belt breaks, will the pistons destroy the valves, or will the engine just stop with just the timing belt to repair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vehicles engine is listed as a 'free-wheeler'. This means that under normal circumstanaces, if the timing belt breaks the pistons and valves will not strike each other. Even so you would need to know why the belt broke and if there is any other damage to the engine which would have caused a breakage.